# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have list of categories and tapping on each of them shows users of that category in new screen. The new screen has an `image` widget and `text` widget. I am getting this error if a user has a `profile picture`, and if there's no profile picture associated with that user, a default picture is shown which doesn't throw this error.

```
Widget _getProfilePic(Pro pro) {

    // If the pro has provided a profile picture
    if(pro.profilePhoto.length > 0) {

      // If the pro is available for a video call
      if(statusMap[pro.onlineStatus] == "Online, available") {
        return CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30.0,
            backgroundImage: pro.profilePhoto.startsWith("./profilepics") ? NetworkImage("" + pro.profilePhoto.substring(2)) : pro.profilePhoto);
      }
      // If pro is not available
      else {
        return CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30.0,
            backgroundImage: pro.profilePhoto.startsWith("./profilepics") ? NetworkImage("" + pro.profilePhoto.substring(2)) : pro.profilePhoto);
      }

    }
    // Else, provide a default icon
    else {
      // If the pro is available for a video call
      if(statusMap[pro.onlineStatus] == "Online, available") {
        var profileImg = Image.asset('icons/default_profile_icon.png', height: 60.0);

        return Image.asset('icons/default_profile_icon.png', height: 60.0);

      }
      // If the pro is not available
      else {
        return Image.asset('icons/default_profile_icon.png', height: 60.0);
      }
    }
```

This is the `Pro` class model:

```
class Pro extends User {
  String company;
  String experience;
  double rating;
  int reviewCount;
  int onlineStatus;
  String proId;

  Pro();

  // Returns a Pro created from JSON
  factory Pro.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    Pro pro = Pro();

    pro.proId = json['ProID'] as String;
    pro.fullname = json['FullName'] as String;
    pro.company = json['Company'] as String;
    pro.experience = json['about'] as String;
    pro.rating = json['ReviewAvg'] != null? double.tryParse(json['ReviewAvg']) : 0.0;
    pro.reviewCount = json['ReviewCount'];
    pro.onlineStatus = json['OnlineStatus'];
    pro.profilePhoto = json['profile_pic'] as String;

    return pro;
  }

}

// Converts a http response body into a List<Pro>
  List<Pro> parsePros(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Pro>((json) => Pro.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to wrap pro.profileImage in NetworkImage in the two places you test for ./profilepics

Comment: Great !! that fixed the issue.